# Mono For Mac 64-Bit

Tags: macos, mono, 64-bit

I need Mono to be 64-bit on my system. Is there a way I can install it? I saw that I could compile it, but the Mono website said that I should not install it into `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run a parallel Mono install, here are the basics that I do to run a 64-bit mono:

1. Assuming you already have the the Xcode (clang/llvm) command line
   tools, if not:

   - Consult the Apple Store for installing Xcode (it is free)
   - And/or
   - Install only the Xcode cmd line tools (xcode-select --install)
   - Check App Store/Software Updates and ensure that all Xcode related items are up to date
2. Get the build dependancies (I use homwbrew, but you can use ports, or build them from source)
3. Get the sources (I use the git-based sources, not the tar balls)
4. Configure mono to build with your requirements
5. Make and install
6. Set/update path

A cmd-line example of the above steps:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config    
git clone http://github.com/mono/mono mono
cd mono
./autogen.sh \
     --with-tls=posix \
     --enable-nls=no \
     --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 \
     --with-glib=embedded \
     --prefix=${HOME}/mono64
make
make install
export PATH=${HOME}/mono64/bin:${PATH}
file `which mono`
  mono: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Note: This does not cover building and linking llvm. I use llvm but the above steps will get you started, once you can get a clean build, consult the Mono docs to add llvm so you can compile to native code instead of just jit'ing. Depending on your code base, the speed difference (2-10x) is well worth it. Also 64-bit AOT'ing to save the startup overhead of llvm'ing to native each time is worth a look.

Required reading to completely understand what these steps are:

[Parallel Mono Environments](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/)

[Mono on OS-X](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/osx/)

[Compiling Mono on OS-X](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/mac/)

Comment: Where would this be installed then?

Comment: I am very new to this. Can you possibly make a full list of steps? I will be very grateful.

Comment: The --prefix option is the one that controls where it will be installed. You need to read the "Compiling Mono on OS-X" link that I placed in the answer as it has also has steps (much like the one I listed). It has additional  details.

Comment: So I would install this in /usr/local?

Comment: Pick a directory, like one in /usr/local/xxxx so all users on the system can access it, or $HOME/xxxx if it only yourself that is using it. It is wise to stay away from /usr/ as the default mono install has links in that directory as the Mono's site says and you will over write them if that is what you choice